# How to display user role on a drawer flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, sidebar, user-roles

I'm currently displaying both email and name on my drawer after user login. Role is stored on firestore.

I'd like to display the user role for example "free or VIP"
but I cannot find the property that fit on `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` Widget any ideas ?

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      accountName: Text(
                        _name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: FontFamily.elgantfamily,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      accountEmail: Text(
                        _email,
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: FontFamily.elgantfamily),
                      ),
                      accountRole: Text(
                      _role,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: FontFamily.elgantfamily,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                       ),
),

_getUserNameandEmail() async {
String uid = await GetStorage().read(sharedPrefrenceKey.uuid);
if (uid != null) {
  _name = GetStorage().read(sharedPrefrenceKey.name);
  _email = GetStorage().read(sharedPrefrenceKey.email);
  _role = GetStorage().read(sharedPrefrenceKey.role);
  setState(() {});
}
}
```

Comment: design your own custom header

Comment: Some Example would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use the `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` you can do it like this

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text('User Name'),
                accountEmail: Text('Email'),
              otherAccountsPictures: [
                Text(
                  'Role',style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red
                ),
                )
              ],
            )
```